# How does tabIndex work for ExtJS fields (confirmation)?

Tags: extjs, tabindex

I've been puzzling over the tabIndex config for ExtJS's Ext.form.field.Base (generic field, in other words). I didn't find much information in the documentation (but then maybe I looked in the wrong place), so I went with trial and error and here's how I understand it now.

- Fields where tabIndex is set explicitly with an integer value strictly greater than 0 are ordered by ascending tabIndex. If several fields have been set with the same tabIndex value, they are sub-ordered by creation: the first field created goes first and so on.
- Fields where tabIndex is set explicitly with 0, or where tabIndex is not set explicitly, go next, with the same sub-order by creation.
- Fields where tabIndex is set exlicitly with an integer value strictly lesser than 0 are out of the order: you cannot reach them with Tab.

(I'll admit that I didn't try to set tabIndex with non-integer values.)

Can someone confirm that this is the way it works, or better yet, point out mistakes or omissions in the above, please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nice folks at sencha have confirmed it : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250586-Can-someone-please-confirm-tabIndex-behavior-with-Ext.form.field.Base&p=918558#post918558

They also pointed out that it was the same in HTML, which is quite right but I had had no inkling of it. Silly me. Well, I hope someone else will find this useful.